# How do you figure out how much gold to give when a monster dies?

Tags: monsters, new-players, treasure

I am new to Dungeons and Dragons. I am curious if anyone can tell me how to determine how much gold to give my fellow players when they slay a monster. I want to give them a lot, but I have heard it may be best to avoid being too generous. Thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: What edition are you playing?

Comment: Also, just to confirm, you are the DM in this group? What resources do you have available (Player's Handbook [PHB], Monster Manual [MM], Dungeon Master's Guide [DMG]) and what resources have you checked yourself?

Comment: I've also voted to hold until we know what edition of D&D. When you've had a chance to [edit] that in--either in the text or (preferably) in the list of tags--the post will be automatically enqueued for (likely) reopening.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Once you edit your question to confirm which edition you're asking about and clarify any other issues, we can hopefully reopen the question and answer it (or direct you to where it has already been answered).